# Field Collection App for Geoserver or Any OS GIS Server

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet, software-recommendations

I am looking for a mobile app/interface for field data collection and mobile editing of GIS data that relies/syncs back to some type of GIS server or database. I am aware of Fulcrum and AmigoCloud, but those are third party. I have yet to roll out a GIS server simply for this reason, I still have to use Collector/Fulcrum/etc to collect the data and have no way to edit the data via mobile. In my initial search for open source GIS server solutions I assumed that this functionality already existed, but I have not yet found a good solution.

Some workarounds I have looked at:

- Google pre-filled Form using gps location from a leaflet map
- Memento database for Android for data collection/synced with google drive
- Various other android gps collection apps
- hosting a uMap installation which allows editing of features
- Appsheet for Google Sheets (comes close but has its limits)
- Mapcentia hosted server (they are supposed to be working on an Android field data collection tool)

Even if the field collection tool could sync to cloud storage that would get me closer.

Comment: Unless I'm missing the point of your post, Collector is able to edit your enterprise database via mobile.  Also,  with the newest release of Collector and Server you are able to do disconnected editing and then sync to your enterprise database whenever you want. My organization has been using disconnected editing with Collector for about a month and have been very satisfied with the results. http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/android/collect-data/offline-use.htm

Comment: I was going to recommend Appsheet but like you mention its not the perfect solution.

Comment: how about http://geopaparazzi.github.io/geopaparazzi/

Comment: In regards to Collector... I work with many clients that do not have a paid ArcGIS Online account, so I could collect the data but they would have no way to edit it or collect any on their own. I am able to host a gis server... Not sure why the open source community has found it so difficult to create a mobile interface like Collector or the other examples for any of the many gis server options out there.

Answer (score -2):

We have written a mobile geospatial data collection and audit app, that works on any browser enabled device (any device as long as it can enable GPS). It is

***a mobile app/interface for field data collection and mobile editing of
GIS data that relies/syncs back to some type of GIS server or database.***

We use our own server (MySQL) and your data is stored on it but can be exported out to a shape or kml file.

Whatever data you collect you can open again on any mobile device and edit/audit/delete the same data.

While not open source it is free up to a point.

The app is called @Map and is found on the website [atmap.com.au](https://atmap.com.au). We use our own independent and unique recordset.

The custom collection form is impossibly easy to set up. You define the table of the feature you want to collect and for each field, define whether it is text, number and whether a dropdown is required. You can specify new options in a dropdown as you collect.

After collection it is possible to export to kml or shape file, or you can leave the data on our server. We use GoogleMaps map images and Leaflet at the moment but as we are a startup, things are fluid.

Disclaimer: I am the Developer of this product.